# windows phone emulator showing chrome

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

How can I remove Windows phone Emulator chrome? My windows phone emulator show chrome at top right corner of emulator. I want to remove that. How can I remove?

[image]

I want to remove number from top right corner.

Comment: Not sure I follow? What are you trying to remove? Perhaps a screenshot could illustrate your issue?

Comment: see the image so that u can get idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those numbers are for diagnostics whilst debugging. In your App.xaml.cs there'll be a block (in the constructor):

```
// Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // Display the current frame rate counters.
    Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

Either commenting the lien out, or setting it to false will remove the counters whilst debugging. In either circumstance, these will not be displayed when invoking your application outside of the debugger.